# Stream read line

Tags: c#, newline, streamreader, tfilestream

I have a stream reader line by line (`sr.ReadLine()`). My code counts the line-end with both line endings `\r\n` and/or `\n`.

```
        StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(sPath, enc);

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            // reading 1 line of datafile
            string sLine = sr.ReadLine();
            ...
```

How to tell to code (instead of universal `sr.ReadLine()`) that I want to count new line only a full `\r\n` and not the `\n`?

Comment: So, do you want the number of occurences of `\r\n` and number of occurences of solo `\n` in the stream?

Comment: Exactly I want to read each line, but the line means till ending by the full `\r\n` and not only `\n`. Other words I can say, that one row can contain any `blah blah \n blah \r\n`

Comment: It is important to know how big is your file to choose the correct way to handle the input-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not possible to do this using StreamReader.ReadLine.
As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A line is defined as a sequence of characters followed by a line feed
>   ("\n"), a carriage return ("\r"), or a carriage return immediately
>   followed by a line feed ("\r\n"). The string that is returned does not
>   contain the terminating carriage return or line feed. The returned
>   value is null if the end of the input stream is reached.

So yoг have to read this stream byte-by-byte and return line only if you've captured \r\n

**EDIT**

Here is some code sample

```
private static IEnumerable<string> ReadLines(StreamReader stream)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    int symbol = stream.Peek();
    while (symbol != -1)
    {
        symbol = stream.Read();
        if (symbol == 13 && stream.Peek() == 10)
        {
            stream.Read();

            string line = sb.ToString();
            sb.Clear();

            yield return line;
        }
        else
            sb.Append((char)symbol);
    }

    yield return sb.ToString();
}
```

You can use it like

```
foreach (string line in ReadLines(stream))
{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: Yes, I was affraid of that :( Can you gimme the sample to submit your answere pls?

Comment: What does those 13 and 10 signify in (symbol == 13 && stream.Peek() == 10)?

Comment: @NoSaidTheCompiler they are ascii codes of \r and \n characters

Answer (score 5):

you cannot do it with ReadLine, but you can do instead:

```
stream.ReadToEnd().Split(new[] {"\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None)
```

Comment: What if stream data is really large? ReadToEnd doesn't seems to be a reasonable solution.

Comment: it always depends on workload, if you need super optimized you can use [StreamReader.Readline source of mono implementation](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/master/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/StreamReader.cs)

Answer (score -1):

For simplification, let's work over a byte array:

```
    static int NumberOfNewLines(byte[] data)
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < data.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (data[i] == '\r' && data[i + 1] == '\n')
                count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
```

If you care about efficiency, optimize away, but this should work.

You can get the bytes of a file by using `System.IO.File.ReadBytes(string filename)`.

Comment: dont use byte[] directly for text, because encoding can create problems

Comment: @EnricoSada so is there some way that in unicode/utf8 these bytes (\n, \r) would be just part of multibyte characters?